# Why does orientation == Orientation.portrait is always true although my device is already in landscape

Tags: flutter, orientation

I am trying to use `OrientationBuilder` in flutter, but the first if statement in my code is always true.

```
        OrientationBuilder(
          builder: (context, orientation) {
            if (orientation == Orientation.portrait) {
              return _portraitMode();
            } else {
              return _landscapeMode();
            }
          },
        ),
```

I am trying to display two different things depending on the screen orientation of my phone. The problem is that, the first if statement is always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current orientation of your device, you can take help of the MediaQuery class and get the orientation like :-

```
    var currOrientation = MediaQuery.of(context).orientation
```

And optimise your code like so,

```
    return currOrientation == Orientation.potrait ? _potraitMode() : _landscapeMode();
```

Hope this helps!